# This code runs smoothly for about 50 seconds, and then starts spamming ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

I'm trying to run this in the google chrome console, it works for about 50 seconds and then spams the error ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES. I'm not sure why it's doing this and I would like some help.

```
var ID = prompt("What ID would you like to go down from?");

function PM(){
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/Groups/Group.aspx?gid=" + ID,function(webpage) {
        if ( $(webpage).find("#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupFundsPane_GroupFunds").length) {
            var funds = $(webpage).find("#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupFundsPane_GroupFunds");
            var robux = $(funds).find(".robux").text();
            var tix = $(funds).find(".tickets").text();
            var owner = $(webpage).find("#ctl00_cphRoblox_OwnershipPanel");
            var owned = $(owner).find("a");
            var ownerhref = owned.text();
            if (ownerhref == "No One!") {
                if (robux != 0 || tix != 0) {
                    console.log("Found a good group. ID is " + groupId + ", It has " + robux + " robux, and " + tix + " tickets!");
                }
            }
        }
        ID = ID - 1;
        setInterval(PM, 300);
    })
}
PM();
```

Comment: so you are calling this function after every 300ms?

Comment: Did you mean `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is running out of resources because the `PM` function is setting up intervals that will recursively call itself in an infinite loop. The [`setInterval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) will call the given function repeatedly (in this case, every 300ms). You could instead use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), which would wait 300ms and then execute the given function once.

To explain your case in detail, the following is what's happening.

1. `PM` is called
2. AJAX call is made, and the callback sets up a new call to `PM` every 300ms
3. Each one of those calls repeats the process from step 1. So, every 300ms, a new interval is set up to call `PM` *again* every 300 ms.

That will look something like this, ad infinitum.

```
PM
 |
 PM..300ms..PM..300ms..PM...
  |          |          |
  |          |          PM..300ms..PM..300ms..PM...
  |          PM..300ms..PM..300ms..PM...
  |           | 
  |           PM..300ms..PM..300ms..PM...
  PM..300ms..PM..300ms..PM...
```